Aristotelian ethics in a world where humans are second-best?
Aristotle's argument for virtue is that we must look to something's function to find what it's most proper pleasure is:

Each animal is thought to have a proper pleasure, as it has a proper function; viz. that which corresponds to its activity.

And that humanity's proper function is the exercise of contemplative reason, which means that it is also the corresponding pleasure.

...But the activity of reason, which is contemplative, seems both to be superior in serious worth and to aim at no end beyond itself, and to have its pleasure proper to itself (and this augments the activity), and the self-sufficiency, leisureliness, unweariedness (so far as this is possible for man), and all the other attributes ascribed to the supremely happy man are evidently those connected with this activity, it follows that this will be the complete happiness of man, if it be allowed a complete term of life (for none of the attributes of happiness is incomplete).

However, since we are mortals, and reason is divine, it will always be partially-out-of-reach. This is further evidence that the exercise of reason and contemplation is the highest virtue:

But such a life would be too high for man; for it is not in so far as he is man that he will live so, but in so far as something divine is present in him; and by so much as this is superior to our composite nature is its activity superior to that which is the exercise of the other kind of virtue. If reason is divine, then, in comparison with man, the life according to it is divine in comparison with human life. But we must not follow those who advise us, being men, to think of human things, and, being mortal, of mortal things, but must, so far as we can, make ourselves immortal, and strain every nerve to live in accordance with the best thing in us; for even if it be small in bulk, much more does it in power and worth surpass everything... And what we said before' will apply now; that which is proper to each thing is by nature best and most pleasant for each thing; for man, therefore, the life according to reason is best and pleasantest, since reason more than anything else is man. This life therefore is also the happiest.

(W. D. Ross translation, X.7)
It seems like this argument relies on reason being the exceptional domain of humans (and gods). For instance, eating is not the sole domain of humans, so we exclude it:

Life seems to be common even to plants, but we are seeking what is peculiar to man. Let us exclude, therefore, the life of nutrition and growth. Next there would be a life of perception, but it also seems to be common even to the horse, the ox, and every animal. (I.7)

If the ancient Greeks were to find a species of deep-sea octopus and then realized that it "contemplates" 2x better than humans (despite being mortal, fallible, etc--they are not 'gods'), does this necessitate a rethinking of what our eudaimonia is? If elephants can reason 25% as well as humans, would reason be their virtue as well?
Did Aristotle or any philosophers in the virtue ethics tradition write about this?

(The question that spurred this was 'could you reconcile Aristotle's ethics with a potential world where AI continues to get better and more general.' But I think the general question maybe has relevance more broadly, e.g. the question about elephants)

Aristotle's problem is that although he defines the specific difference of humans as rational animals, he never explains specifically and formally what reason consists of, hence your question. To make the argument work, one must always maintain a specific difference between the soul of man and that of other animals and plants.
But I think you are positing a non sequitur: for human beings and insofar as their world is concerned, eudaimonia would still operate, because we are essentially rational. By nature, we desire to know, and contemplation would remain the highest object of our life.
